# Disable Please visit the Update Network page to update all your sites. Notice from Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I would like to Hide below message you see on dashboard after wordpress version upgrade in Wordpress MU.

I know for hiding version upgrade notice there is one filter as

add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

But I want to disable the following notice

"Thank you for Updating! Please visit the Update Network page to update all your sites."[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message was fired on two hooks.

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
add_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );

Remove this and you remove the message, use remove_action.

To remove this function use a function, like the follow example.

add_action( 'admin_menu','fb_hide_site_notice' );
function fb_hide_site_notice() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'site_admin_notice' );
}